# Unit test a .NET core (2.0) application from Visual Studio. .NET core not present as targetframework

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I created a .NET core 2.0 webpages project.

Then I created a unit test project in which I wanted to test one of the pagemodels.

I then got this message:

```
Project 'C:\projects\[removed].csproj' targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
```

Indeed, my testproject targets 4.6.1 so I wanted to change that to .NET core 2.0 also.
But I don't see any of the .NET core frameworks in the dropdownlist where I can pick a framework. I see all 'regular' .NET versions.
At the webproject I see ONLY the .NET core projects but not the 'regular' .NET versions.

[image]

I saw an option in the dropdown in the testproject to 'install more versions' so I did install the .NET core 2.0 SDK and runtime but that didn't help.

Running VS2017 15.4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you created the Unit Test Project you probably did not pick the .NET Core template for unit testing.

[image]

You can can edit your csproj file (right click and edit) of your current Unit Testing project and change to the desired target framework:

```
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
```

You find a list of all supported monikers for the target framework node here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks

Comment: Thanks very much. Feels a bit silly that I didn't look at the '.NET core' folder. I only looked in the 'Test' folder, and there it only showed the full-.NET version. But end of the story, it works!